# Algorithm, that finds the k-greatest number in O(n*log(k))

Tags: python-3.x

was wondering, if you have given an unsorted list of arrays of any length n >= k,
what is your idea, to find the k-greatest number in O(n*log(k)) time. So the k = 2 -greatest number of an Array containing the numbers 1 to 9 would be 8 for example.

I'm trying to code this in python, if you have an idea how in that time complexity :)

Comment: well if n <= k we could sort descending in O(n log(n)) and just access the kth element

Comment: this is meant as a worst case runtime unfortunately, so the case k <= n would always apply

Comment: please check your post. In your post you state n <= k. However your last comment suggests that is instead k <= n

Comment: oopsie my bad, ima fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is not python-specific, however you should be able to implement the used concepts in python, or find libraries already implementing them.

The basic idea is to iterate over the list and store the current greatest, second greatest, ... , k-greatest number in a separate data structure. Since you will be iterating over all n entries in your array, the complexity of this is in `O(n * insertion_step_complexity)`
As seen above, the insertion step needs to not exceed a complexity of `O(log(k))` to achieve this you can use a `AVL-Tree` that has a complexity of `O(log(m))` for inserting and deleting items, where `m` is the number of items stored within the avl-tree.

An algorithm would look like this:

```
def find_k_greatest_number(k, array):
    avl_tree = initialize AVL tree here
    avl_items = 0
    for number in array:
        if (number > avl_tree.smallest_number()):
            if (avl_itmes >= k):
                avl_tree.delete_smallest_number()
            else:
                avl_items++
            avl_tree.insert(number)
    return avl_tree.smallest_number()
```

Finding the smallest number in a sorted tree is dependent on its height. Since the AVL tree can't exceed the height of `log(k)` the complexity of finding the smallest number is `O(log(k))`.

Comment: Ok, so far i see what the approach is, though, this would return the k-smallest element wouldnt it? If I interpret this code correctly, the for loop should take O(n), smallest_number(), delete_smallest_number() and insert(number) O(log(m)). 
So adding that all up, this would be at O(log(m)*n) right? I am ignoring the step(because that is doable in the same iteration) of checking for the correct height of each altered element and their parents after each function, to make sure, that the balance is kept in the range of (-1,1), or rebalancing, if its no longer the case.

Comment: Is always O(log(m)*n) ∈ O(log(k)*n) in that case?

Comment: Your interpretation of the code is not entirely correct. There are two important data structures here `array` which holds your original array and `avl_tree` which in iteration `i` of the loop holds the greatest to k-greatest number of the subarray `[a0 ... ai]` where `ax` is the xth element of the array. When going into a new iteration `i` we check if `ai` is bigger than the smallest element of the `avl_tree`. Since `avl_tree` consists of the greatest elements of the subarray `[a0...a(i-1)]` if `ai` is larger than the smallest element we delete the smallest element from the `avl_tree`....

Comment: Because since it is the k-th largest element in ´[a0...a(i-1)]` it is the (k+1) largest element in `[a0,...,ai]` and therefore storage is no longer needed. Then we insert the current element `ai` into the `avl_tree`. SInce it was larger than the k+1 largest element its guaranteed to be at least the k-th largest element.

Comment: As for the complexity `O(log(m)*n) ∈ O(log(k)*n)` is not true in all cases. The key here is that the `avl_tree` holds at most k elements. so since the complexity for insertion and deletion operations is `O(log(m))` for an avl-tree with `m` elements the complexity of the operations within the for loop do not exceed `O(log(k))`

Comment: ok, i do understand now, the tree may only be out of k elements...so worst case would be, if we had to build the tree out of n elements, still log(k) would apply. Mindblowing, thank you very much :)
Initially, i wanted to know, how ppl would solve this, because this was an assignement in an exam, which recommended the usage of heaps to achieve that time. AVL Trees seem to be the better alternative though now. And somehow they said O(n+log(k)*k) was an acceptable time too.

Comment: A heap works because it as well has an insertion and deletion complexity of `O(log m)` so you could just replace the avl_tree with a heap and get similar results

Comment: ty for the answer :) do you know how to mark this as answered?

Comment: There should be a tick next to my answer (somewhere in the area of the up and downvotes). if you click it it should become green and the answer will be marked as accepted